# Terraform Error: Argument or block definition required when I run TF plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, syntax, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I have 2 rds instances being created and when running tf plan I am getting a terraform error regarding unsupported block type:

```
Error: Unsupported block type

  on rds.tf line 85, in module "rds":
  85: resource "random_string" "rds_password_dr" {

Blocks of type "resource" are not expected here.

Error: Unsupported block type

  on rds.tf line 95, in module "rds":
  95: module "rds_dr" {

Blocks of type "module" are not expected here.
```

This is my code in my rds.tf file:

```
# PostgreSQL RDS App Instance
module "rds" {
  source = "git@github.com:************"

  name           = var.rds_name_app
  engine         = var.rds_engine_app
  engine_version = var.rds_engine_version_app
  family         = var.rds_family_app
  instance_class = var.rds_instance_class_app

  # WARNING: 'terraform taint random_string.rds_password' must be run prior to recreating the DB if it is destroyed
  password                   = random_string.rds_password.result
  port                       = var.rds_port_app
  "
  "

# PostgreSQL RDS DR Password
resource "random_string" "rds_password_dr" {
  length           = 16
  override_special = "!&*-_=+[]{}<>:?"

  keepers = {
    rds_id = "${var.rds_name_dr}-${var.environment}-${var.rds_engine_dr}"
  }
}

# PostgreSQL RDS DR Instance
module "rds_dr" {
  source = "git@github.com:notarize/terraform-aws-rds.git?ref=v0.0.1"

  name           = var.rds_name_dr
  engine         = var.rds_engine_dr
  engine_version = var.rds_engine_version_dr
  family         = var.rds_family_dr
  instance_class = var.rds_instance_class_dr

  # WARNING: 'terraform taint random_string.rds_password' must be run prior to recreating the DB if it is destroyed
  password                   = random_string.rds_password.result
  port                       = var.rds_port_dr
  "
  "
```

I don't know why I am getting this? Someone please help me.

Comment: What's in the line ` on rds.tf line 129, `?

Comment: @Marcin pls see question I changed it to more detail

Answer (score 3):

You haven't closed the `module` blocks (`module "rds"` and `module "rds_dr"`). You also have a couple of strange double-quotes at the end of both `module` blocks.

Remove the double-quotes and close the blocks (with `}`).

Comment: @Ixop I do not think this fixed the problem, I tried. Can u please take a look at the code again?

Comment: @Myra what do you mean "I do not think this fixed the problem"? Does the problem still exist after making the changes or does it not? Your updated code has an extra `}` at the end. The error you have listed in your question doesn't match the updated code, please update the error too, if you still get one.

Comment: @Ixop yes I just updated question with the new error I am getting.. also sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: This is a new problem, which needs a new question. I'll roll back your changes; please create a new question for a new problem. When you do so, please make sure you show the relevant code - the error you have shown doesn't belong to the code you have shown